# Porterduff Mode DST_IN drawing a rectangle around path

Tags: android, canvas, path, mask

I'm attempting to draw a path, and then mask it with another path using the DST_IN Porterduff Mode.

Here's my block of code that does the drawing

```
int saveCount = canvas.saveLayer(
  0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), null);
canvas.drawPath(mPath, mFillPaint);  
mClipPaint = new Paint();
mClipPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));
canvas.drawPath(mClipPath, mClipPaint);
```

This does the masking but also has a rectangle around the path beyond which the masking doesn't work as seen below. The outer star is the original path and the blob is the masking path. You can see that the blob has a rectangular border beyond which masking doesn't work 
[image]

As a side note, this only seems to work if hardware acceleration is enabled. Is this expected?